# Angular 7: How to transform query params within subscription?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, query-string

I'd like to transform query parameters to integers within subscription, but for some reason the code after any of the transformations of query parameters to integers (or any other type as well) results in code stop executing.

```
combineLatest(params, queryParams, (params, qparams) => ({ params, qparams }))
      .subscribe(allParams => {
        this.item.color = allParams.qparams['color'] || allParams.params['color'] || ''; //this line must be above
        this.item.price = parseInt(allParams.qparams['price']) || 0; //this line also
        this.items.features = allParams.qparams['features'].map(feature => parseInt(feature));
      });
```

Map (or any other transformation I've tried) work, but the lines below it don't execute. I don't know if the problem is connected with

- using arrays (`features` is an array);
- calling synchronous functions (map) within async.;
- something else entirely.

I'd appreciate any suggestion as to what's happening.

Comment: Could you add the error thrown while executing this code?

Comment: There is no error shown, I've just seen it after adding console.log below each line.

Comment: Can you `console.log(allParams)` and share the output with us?

Comment: What `params` is? what `queryParams` is? Please share some more code. What benefit does `combineLatest` has in your code over a simple subscription to `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: It's URL parameters and query parameters (for keeping the data on refresh)

Comment: @user2216584, I will when I'll get to computer, but I think allParams.params or allParams.queryparams are like this: empty object or when full: {color: 'white', price: '17', features: ['22', '23']}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the usage of `combineLatest` is not redundant in your scenario. I'd even take the leap and say that this is your issue, since `combineLatest` will wait for all its' supplied observables to emit an initial value (and from your code, it seems like this might not happen).
I'd do something like that:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute)  {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.item.color = '';
    this.item.price = 0;
    this.item.features = [];
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
       this.item.color = queryParams['color'] || '';
       this.item.price = queryParams['price'] || 0;
       this.item.features = queryParams['features'].map(feature => parseInt(feature));
    });

    // ...Do the same with this.route.params
}
```

If you want to use `combineLatest` but not to passively wait for an initial value, you can pipe one with `.pipe(startWith(null))`:

```
combineLatest(params.pipe(startWith(null)), queryParams.pipe(startWith(null)), (params, qparams) => ({ params, qparams })) ....
```

or... you can use [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) instead of `combineLatest`.

Comment: But I need also to get the parameters (not just query parameters), is there a way to do that? And if I leave these transformation methods out, it all works perfectly. Very interesting about waiting for the initial values, thank you! I'll have that in mind in future.

Comment: @Mandy please see my edit regarding the usage of combineLatest. This may solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try and let you know! Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Zip works the same in this case as combineLatest, while the other methods didn't work at all. I must be missing something, but have no idea what. Just wanted to let you know, thank you for your kindness and time all the same!